# SBT: add third party library dependency but NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, sbt, apache-spark

I use `sbt` to build my Scala project.

Here is my `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "SpatialSpark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.vividsolutions" % "jts" % "1.13"
```

Then I try to package it into jar. `sbt package`

Finally, I submit this to `Apache-Spark`,

```
spark-submit --class "com.chen.spatial.SpatialApp" --master local[4] target/scala-2.10/spatialspark_2.10-1.0.jar
```

It causes **NoClassDefFoundError** error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vividsolutions/jts/index/strtree/STRtree
```

Did I miss something when packing it into jar?

Answer (score 2):

You should create an [uber jar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and after running

```
sbt assembly
```

it should work

Comment: Why `sbt` doesn't have built-in plugin providing such feature?

Comment: I dont know others(like gradle) but  Maven doesn't has one as well.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please upvote and/or accept the answer please :)

Answer (score 2):

Please look at this template project:

https://github.com/spektom/spark-scala-template

To build the uberjar run:

```
sbt assembly
```

To run the Jar in Spark:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class com.github.spark.App spark-scala-assembly-0.0.1.jar
```